# Authenticating with a 3rd party Oauth1.0 server from a native app

Tags: android, ios, api, rest, oauth

I am developing mobile apps that interact with a 1st party REST api. I want to be able to pull in data from a 3rd party rest api that uses Oauth1.0 authentication, but I don't want to have to host an html page for the redirects and force the native app to open a web browser to login to the api.

Is there any way for the mobile apps to perform the authentication then send their token information to my 1st party REST api, where I can then use that information to query the 3rd party api?

Answer (score 0):

OAuth1.0 has this main criticism that Mobile and Desktop apps that it needs to open up browser to take the credentials and authenticate against the service provider. This is one of the issues addressed in OAuth2.0

So the solution is to either OAuth2.0 (better one) or to live with the mobile app UX making the switch to the browser in between to authenticate users.